# Error in dbgheap.c trying to realloc *add space to array*

Tags: c

Creating a priority queue for school.  Used an array of pointers to the object to keep the information.  I want to be able to dynamically add more space to the array if the number of entries gets too big.  Below is how I am initting the original size of the array.  pq_max is 1024 to begin.  Since it's a tree structure I just want to double the size if it needs more room.

So, I tell my insert function to call pq_addMem if more room is needed, but it fails.  After further debugging, i'm passing a bad pointer or a pointer from a nonlocal heap.

I'm  used to C++ and assume that I'm reallocating memory incorrectly, but can't figure out why.  If answer isn't obvious to someone I'll post the rest of the code.

```
pq->Array = (pq_entry_t*) malloc( sizeof(pq_entry_t) * (pq->pq_max) );

void pq_addMem(pq_t* pq)
{
    pq_entry_t *newArray;
    pq->pq_max *= 2;
    newArray = (pq_entry_t*) realloc(pq->Array, sizeof(pq_entry_t) * pq->pq_max);
    if (newArray == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    } 
    else
    {                                   
        pq->Array = newArray;
    }
}
```

The place of failure.

```
      /*
     * If this ASSERT fails, a bad pointer has been passed in. It may be
     * totally bogus, or it may have been allocated from another heap.
     * The pointer MUST come from the 'local' heap.
     */
    _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData));
```

Comment: What do you see when stepping through in the debugger? Is `pq->Array` always valid? If you're really seeing a symptom of heap corruption the culprit could be _anywhere_ in your code (it's not going to be in the CRT)

Comment: Ok, I did something silly.  I put a break point in that function to see what was going on, so I was seeing TRUE flags during the malloc and not realloc() call.  Durr.  So the realloc() breaks on the first call of the CRT, even though it passes the 2 if statements.  And if I debug it it just says "you have trigged a breakpoint".  If I run it the program just exits and says nothing.  Without this function, and keeping within bounds of pq->Array the program works just fine.

Comment: If you breakpoint the return if `newArray == NULL`, do you hit that before you crash?

Comment: No, it crashes on the previous line.

Comment: Edited: Dies on this line in dbgheap.c : _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData));    Must be bad pointer, hrmmm

Comment: If I drop my max value to 500 and realloc to 1000 it works.  Seems to not work if I go much over 1000.  Maybe overrunning heap/stack? Though each array should only be about 12 bytes wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really only two possibilities here - either `pq->Array` is being modified to something other than the return value of a `malloc()` or `realloc()`, which invokes undefined behaviour when you pass it to `realloc()`, or the heap is getting corrupted somehow, in which case *pretty much anything can happen*.

Pointers are easy enough to debug - breakpoint every `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` to make sure the value isn't changing in between. If it is, track down when, then where, then why.

Heap corruption on the other hand is generally a right pain to debug, since you usually only see the symptoms some time after it occurs, and the errors you get are often nonsense and only tell you *something went wrong*.

Now, there is a potential heap corruption waiting to happen in the code posted, but it doesn't seem to be the one causing this crash. Consider when `realloc()` runs out of memory here:

1. insert function calls `pq_addMem()` for more space
2. `pq_addMem()` doubles `pq->pq_max`
3. `realloc()` returns `NULL`, `pq->Array` remains the same size.
4. `pq_addMem()` returns.
5. insert function sees `pq->pq_max` is now larger, proceeds to insert nodes off the end of the array overwriting internal heap data.
6. ...
7. later call to memory management function tries to interpret corrupted heap, all hell breaks loose.

Double-check all your pointer and array accesses, make sure everything really is the size you think it is, and look out for the sneaky stuff like inadvertently `malloc()`'ing 0 bytes then trying to actually *use* the pointer it happily returns.

Comment: Yah, something wonky is happening.  I had to go to class, but I'm back and will be rewriting my memory allocations from scratch (only a few places anyways). Without rewriting some things I can't see the data because everything is a void* pointer to allow for any object.  I learned that you can't dereference those.  I'll have to just create a struct to throw data in or verify the actual addresses.  Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that something is writing outside the array and thus corrupting the heap. This is then causing the `ASSERT` in `dbgheap.c` to think it's not a valid heap pointer. Alternatively, something is overwriting `pq->Array` so it really is not a valid heap pointer.

`valgrind` is a useful tool to use to debug this sort of thing.

Comment: I probably need to learn more about how exactly the heap is used.  And I will look into valgrind.